# What does RW mean in the FLIR Spinnaker software?

Tags: python-3.x, flir, pyspin, spinnaker-cam

In the FLIR documentation of PySpin/Spinnaker there is no reference to PySpin.RW. What does it mean?

It is used as follows:

`if cam.TriggerMode.GetAccessMode() != PySpin.RW:`

Obviously its there for test/comparision reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FLIR website I can find the following [here](https://www.flir.com/support-center/iis/machine-vision/application-note/feature-locking-in-spinnaker-api/):

Read-only nodes

For some features, the node is read-only and cannot be unlocked under any circumstances. The node is provided for information purposes.

To determine if a node is read-only:

In SpinView, double-click on the feature to open the Node Information window. Look for the AccessMode row.

> Access    Description
>
> 1. RO     Read-only
> 2. RW     Read / Write
> 3. N/A    Not Available

Using Spinnaker API, you can poll the Access Mode with the following:

```
//! Checks if a node is readable
inline bool IsReadable (const IBase* p)
{
   return (p != NULL) && IsReadable (p->GetAccessMode());
}
```